# Merge multiple Isochrones

Tags: r, overlapping-features, sf, routing, isochrone

I have 2 Isochrone maps generated by OpenRouteService (using the R package). Each segment represents a walk of 60 seconds, 300 seconds in total.
Since both starting points are quite near, the isochrones overlap and create a really messy map. I would like to merge the isochrones that contain the same value. I have tried so far to merge the Isochrones using st_difference and st_union, but it did not work.
[image]

Comment: If what you want is the minimum time to get to a location starting at either of the two points, then a simple merge isn't going to work - you want the minimum value of the overlapping polygons. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes, I want the minimum value of the overlapping polygons.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail on the isochrone data structure you have? For the map above is it a spatial features polygon object with 10 rows, each row has some sort of time value, and each polygon is a complete filled polygon and its not a set of nested rings? The darkening in your map is due to opacity combining as at the centre of each set you have five overlapping polygons?